# I want to connect to an external DB

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I want to connect to SQLserver that I want to use for reference separately from MYSQL which is the main DB
To do that, set

**.env**

```
#mysql
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=hogedb
DB_USERNAME=hoge
DB_PASSWORD=password

#SQLserver
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=databasename
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

**user**

```
protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';
```

I geted error

> could not find driver (SQL: select * from [user] where [user].[deleted_at] is null)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**.env**:

```
#mysql
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=hogedb
DB_USERNAME=hoge
DB_PASSWORD=password

#SQLserver
DB_SQL_HOST=localhost
DB_SQL_DATABASE=databasename
DB_SQL_USERNAME=username
DB_SQL_PASSWORD=password
```

And `config/database.php`:

```
 'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_SQL_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_SQL_DATABASE', ''),
        'username' => env('DB_SQL_USERNAME', ''),
        'password' => env('DB_SQL_PASSWORD', ''),
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
],
```

Then use in **user** - `protected $connection = "sqlsrv";`
Finally run `php artisan config:cache`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured your `config/database.php` file?

Try to configure it like this

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'        => 'mysql',
        'host'          => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port'          => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database'      => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database_1'), //forge
        'username'      => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'), // forge
        'password'      => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
         .......
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'        => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'          => env('DB_HOST_SQLSRV', '127.0.0.1'), // Notice that we change the default so that it'll refer to another variable which will be DB_HOST_SQLSRV in the .env file
        'port'          => env('DB_PORT_SQLSRV', '1433'),
        'database'      => env('DB_DATABASE2_SQLSRV', 'database_2'),
        'username'      => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'), // Remains as is if you won't change the username and password, change it if you need to
        'password'      => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        .......
   ],
```

In your .env file it should look like this

```
// Mysql
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=hogedb
DB_USERNAME=hoge
DB_PASSWORD=password

// SQL Server
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv // We call in the 'sqlsrv' that we configured in database.php
DB_HOST_SQLSRV=localhost
DB_PORT_SQLSRV=1433 // DON'T FORGET THIS, IT'S VERY IMPORTANT!
DB_DATABASE2_SQLSRV=databasename // We change 'DB_Database' to 'DB_Database2'
DB_USERNAME=root // We may not add this to the second one unless you configured for another username & password in database.php
DB_PASSWORD=
```

So basically what you've configured in the database.php will fetch the data from your `.env`, if you notice it has the word **env** `env('DB_PORT_SQLSRV', '1433')`

Don't forget to run `php artisan config:cache` after changing something in the config folder